# disable android bluetooth

Tags: android

I have the code that enables the blueooth on a device.

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
```

I am wondering how can I disable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [`BluetoothAdapter.disable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#disable%28%29) function. You should ask a user before disabling bluetooth though.

Don't forget to add next permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use `.disable` and `.enable` with the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission.